# Windows forms application UI behaviour is different on windows7/8 and windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, windows-10

I have a Winforms application in which I made the changes for it to adapt to different resolutions and DPI. I made the changes according to a windows 10 device and the application looks proper when run on Windows 10 with **125% DPI** settings. But when the same application is run on Windows 7 or 8  the UI behavior is altogether different.

Also the other difference I observed was that the application was DPI aware on Windows 7 & 8 by default whereas in windows 10 it's not. I get two different outputs for the following code.

```
private float GetCurrentDpi()
{
   float dx, dy;

   using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
   {
      dx = g.DpiX;
      dy = g.DpiY;

   }

   return dx > dy ? dx : dy;

}
```

**Outputs:**

Windows 10 - **96**   no matter what the DPI setting is( unless I add the manifest file with DPI aware setting to true).

Windows 7/8 - whatever the current DPI setting is e.g. 120, 144 etc.

> What I want?
>
> I want the application to behave the way it behaves on windows 10 on
>   all Windows 7,8,8.1,10. Even if it means making the application DPI unaware

Comment: "unless I add the manifest file with DPI aware setting to true" - ever thought that this is what you should do? Does it have negative impact on Windows 7/8?

Comment: @ThomasWeller The UI looks better without this setting on Windows 10. It does have a negative impact on windows 10. On Windows 7/8 the odd behavior replicates even without the manifest file.

Comment: Now I don't understand the request any more. Sorry.

Comment: Wow! no answers at all but a down vote out of nowhere. Mind specifying the reason if any?

Comment: the Graphics object always returns 96 DPI. Use the GetDpiForMonitor to get the real data: http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/get-screen-scaling/4755

Comment: @magicandre1981 "the Graphics object always returns 96 DPI", not true not always I've mentioned the two cases above where it returns the right value. The only question here is that how do I stop the default windows scaling ? I've already designed a way to scale the application to different resolutions.

Comment: for me it always returned 96, no matter what I select (125, 150%).